# How can I return an XML message from PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am having some trouble mixing PHP with XML.

I currently have a PHP file that takes variables from the URL string and I need to calculate something based on these variables, and then return the output in an XTML format.

I currently have my main config file that links to my xml generating file:

```
include('Xml.php');

$x = new xml();
$x->generate();
```

And my XML generating file is as follows:

```
<?php

Class XML {

public function generate() {
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc->formatOutput = true;

    $root = $doc->createElement('conv');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    $at = $doc->createElement('at');
    $at = $root->appendChild($at);

    $text = $doc->createTextNode("hi");
    $text = $at->appendChild($text);

    echo $doc->saveXML();
}
}
?>
```

But this doesn't work - what am I doing wrong here - I know it's probaby obvious but I am new to XML and can't seem to get it working!

Should I be doing it differently? If so ... how?

Comment: how exactly it `doesn't work` ?

Comment: I think everything is ok with your code. Try in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your class with following code:

```
$xml = new XML();
$xml->generate();
```

And I've got this result:

```
[vyktor@grepfruit tmp]$ php test.php 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<conv>
  <at>hi</at>
</conv>
```

So your class works just fine and your error is somewhere else, eg. including wrong file.

Turn on `error_reporting` and paste errors in comment.